# How to enable URL Rewrite in IIS with a .NET Core website

Tags: iis, .net-core, url-rewriting, web-config

I have created / maintained .net mvc websites for many years and I am working on my first .net core website.  I am using Windows server 2019 with IIS.  My goal is to duplicate the rewrite rules I have created for my mvc websites on my new core website (one example is the canonical host name rule).  I don't have any problems doing this in IIS for the new core website.  My problem is when I publish changes, the web.config file on the server gets overwritten and the rules are removed (because I created them in IIS not in Visual Studio).  .net core does not have a web.config file in Visual Studio to modify, but a default version is sent to the server when publishing.

Here is the default version if this helps:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\websitename.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 81d237a0-1b33-43a4-8e2b-eed282153721-->
```

I resolved this issue by adding the below lines to the project file, which turns off creating/transforming the web.config file when publishing:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <IsTransformWebConfigDisabled>true</IsTransformWebConfigDisabled>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

My question is if my approach is an appropriate way to implement url rewrites?  I am using IIS, so a web.config file is required, but it isn't something I can edit in Visual Studio for core like I could for mvc (at least I am not aware of how to do it).

Comment: When you open your project in VS, do you have your own `web.config`? When you run `dotnet publish` to generate deployment bits, what's the content in `web.config`? You didn't even describe clearly your "approach" so edits to this question is mandatory.

Comment: I suggest you create rewrite rules directly in iis. [Creating Rewrite Rules for the URL Rewrite Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module).

Comment: @Lex Li - I updated the question specifying that there is not a web.config in visual studio and added the default web.config file that is created by visual studio.  In response to clearly describing my "approach", I felt that I did describe what I had done: updating the visual studio project file to not overwrite the web.config file on publish and adding the rewrite rules on the server through the IIS rewrite module.

Comment: @samwu - That is what I did.  I added the rewrite rules in IIS.  The problem was that the rules were being removed on publish, because the web.config file was being overwritten.

Comment: Then unfortunately you need to include a web.config of your own in VS.